# What does - int *p() - mean in c?

Tags: c, pointers

What does this definition mean in C language? A pointer to what?

```
int  *a();
```

Comment: function returns a pointer to integer

Comment: Open your C book, look in the section called "Pointers"...

Answer (score 4):

```
int  *a();
```

is the declaration of a function that takes an unspecified (but fixed) number of arguments and returns an `int *`.

It is different than:

```
int *a(void);
```

which is the declaration of a function that takes no argument and returns an `int *`.

The former declaration is an obsolescent feature, use the second form to declare a function with no parameter.

Comment: I didn't know that. I really didn't

Comment: @iharob no problem, this website is always a good place to learn new stuff

Comment: then what is the meaning of - int  (*a) ();?

Comment: @user3540460 a pointer to a function with an unspecified number of parameters and that returns an `int`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `cdecl` command by typing

```
explain int  *a()
```

and you will get

```
cdecl> explain int  *a()
declare a as function returning pointer to int
```